# iOS convert Universal to iPad app - not working

Tags: ios, ipad, universal

I have a universal iOS application with multiple storyboards. first storyboard is for login, once the authentication is done, the second one (split view controller) handles some tasks to be added to the system. Upon selecting a specific task, another set of storyboards come into play to provide task specific functionality.

Now, for quick time to market, we had to go with iPad only and cannot support iPhone for now. So, i ended up changing my 'universal' app to 'iPad' and find strange things happening. Now all of a sudden, when the user logs in and moves from storyboard 1 to 2, iOS complains that there's no storyboard with a given identifier. This is a fully functionaly iOS app. Setting the devices as 'universal' works properly on iPad, however, setting devices to 'iPad' results in storyboard identifier not found exception.

Can't i covert a 'universal' app to 'ipad' straight ? are there any specific steps required for converting a universal app to iPad ?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: Is this the first release of the prduct, such as v1.0? Or is this an update of an older version of the app?

Comment: It is not in the app store yet. it's the first version of the app.

Comment: Okei. Did you set the app as universal when you frist setup the app in iTunes Connect? This might causing you some trouble.

Comment: Yes. However, my problem right now is not even with iTunes Connect. I am trying to change the app mode from 'universal' to 'iPad' and running it on my local iPad to see if things are working fine and that's where i am running into the issue described above.